# Agregar un listview personalizado en un fragmento

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, listview

Estoy tratando de utilizar un listview personalizado en un fragmento, ya busqué en varias páginas y ya busqué en este foro, pero no logro ubicarme para adaptarlo a lo mío.

Mi problema es que en código no logro hacer que compile el adaptador personalizado, "truena" la aplicación al inflar el fragmento, y con un "(AppCompatActivity)" agregado no "truena" pero no muestra nada el listview.

¿Hay algo que pueda hacer?
¿Debería intentar otra cosa?

Este es el código del fragmento en el que quiero mostrar el listview personalizado:

```
private ArrayList<ListaHistorial> listaCalificaciones;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_historial, container, false);
    listaCalificaciones = new ArrayList<>();

    listaCalificaciones.add(new ListaHistorial("Math", 10, "9/1/2017 13:45"));
    listaCalificaciones.add(new ListaHistorial("Math", 8, "7/5/2017 10:50"));
    listaCalificaciones.add(new ListaHistorial("Marh", 4, "7/7/2017 16:30"));
    listaCalificaciones.add(new ListaHistorial("Math", 5, "4/15/2017 15:00"));
    listaCalificaciones.add(new ListaHistorial("Math", 7, "3/10/2017 10:29"));

    AdaptadorHistorial adaptador = new AdaptadorHistorial(HistorialFragment.this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaCalificaciones);
    //AdaptadorHistorial adaptador = new AdaptadorHistorial(, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaCalificaciones);

    ListView list1 = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list1);
    list1.setAdapter(adaptador);

    return view;
}

private class AdaptadorHistorial extends ArrayAdapter<ListaHistorial>{
    AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;

    AdaptadorHistorial(AppCompatActivity context){
        super(context, R.layout.lista_historial, listaCalificaciones);
        appCompatActivity = context;
    }

    /*public AdaptadorHistorial(FragmentActivity activity, int simple_list_item_1, ArrayList<ListaHistorial> listaCalificaciones) {
        super(activity, simple_list_item_1, listaCalificaciones);
    }*/

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = appCompatActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_historial, null);

        TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
        tv1 = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.tv3);

        tv1.setText(listaCalificaciones.get(position).getExamen());
        tv2.setText(listaCalificaciones.get(position).getCalificacion());
        tv3.setText(listaCalificaciones.get(position).getFecha());

        return item;
    }
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Este es el XML con la interfaz de cada objeto del listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="" />
```

Y esta es la clase que cree para representar cada objeto del listview

class ListaHistorial {
    private String examen, fecha;
    private int calificacion;

```
public ListaHistorial(String examen, int calificacion, String fecha)
{
    this.examen = examen;
    this.calificacion = calificacion;
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getExamen() {
    return examen;
}

public int getCalificacion(){
    return calificacion;
}

public String getFecha(){
    return fecha;
}
```

}

Aquí es donde muestra el error, lo que no compila:

```
AdaptadorHistorial adaptador = new AdaptadorHistorial(HistorialFragment.this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaCalificaciones);
```

Me suelta este error al intentar correr el programa:

```
Error:(39, 40) error: constructor AdaptadorHistorial in class HistorialFragment.AdaptadorHistorial cannot be applied to given types;
```

required: AppCompatActivity
found: FragmentActivity,int,ArrayList
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Si necesito mostrar algo más, por favor, díganme.
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Has probado utilizando `getActivity()`  en vez de `HistorialFragment.this.getActivity()`?

Comment: @David No veo ningún cambio, me aparece el mismo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resolví el problema, era algo... insignificante, pero que de un principio no tenía claro y es algo que nunca encontré en vídeos ni en tutoriales, pero sí era algo lógico.
La razón por la que mi programa "tronaba" es porque intentaba poner un dato int en un TextView del ListView personalizado, los cuales tienen como formato nativo String, y no hacía la correcta asignación de texto... Así que aquí pongo el como quedó al final la clase AdaptadorHistorial, ya que este es el único que tuve que modificar:

```
private class AdaptadorHistorial extends ArrayAdapter<ListaHistorial>{
        ...
        String paraTVCalificacion = String.valueOf(listaCalificaciones.get(position).getCalificacion());
        ...
    }
}
```

El error corregido se encuentra en la parte comentada.

Answer (score 2):

Estás creando un listview personalizado por lo cual necesitas que tu Adapter herede de BaseAdapter, te comparto como deberías de implementarlo:

```
private class AdaptadorHistorial extends BaseAdapter {

    //Propiedades
    ArrayList<ListaHistorial>  listaCalificaciones;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    //Constructor
    public AdaptadorHistorial(Context context, ArrayList<ListaHistorial> listaCalificaciones) {

        this.listaCalificaciones = listaCalificaciones;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    //Base Adapter

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listaCalificaciones.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }


    //Holder para crear View de cada item de la lista

    class Holder {
        //Propiedades
        TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_customlistview, null);
        Holder holder = new Holder();

        //Init item_customlistivew
        holder.tv1 =  rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        holder.tv2 =  rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        holder.tv3 =  rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);

        holder.tv1.setText(listaCalificaciones.get(position).getExamen());
        holder.tv2.setText("" + listaCalificaciones.get(position).getCalificacion());
        holder.tv3.setText(listaCalificaciones.get(position).getFecha());


        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Esta es la manera en la que se implementa en tu fragment

```
public class CustomListFragment extends Fragment {

//Propiedades
AdaptadorHistorial adaptadorHistorial;
ArrayList<ListaHistorial> listaCalificaciones;

//View
View rootView;
ListView lvCustom;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customlistview, container, false);
    lvCustom = rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvCustom);

    listaCalificaciones = new ArrayList<>();
    listaCalificaciones.add(new ListaHistorial("Math", 10, "9/1/2017 13:45"));
    listaCalificaciones.add(new ListaHistorial("Math", 8, "7/5/2017 10:50"));
    listaCalificaciones.add(new ListaHistorial("Marh", 4, "7/7/2017 16:30"));
    listaCalificaciones.add(new ListaHistorial("Math", 5, "4/15/2017 15:00"));
    listaCalificaciones.add(new ListaHistorial("Math", 7, "3/10/2017 10:29"));

    adaptadorHistorial = new AdaptadorHistorial(getActivity(), listaCalificaciones);

    lvCustom.setAdapter(adaptadorHistorial);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Asi se se inicia el fragment desde el activity

```
public class CustomListView extends AppCompatActivity {

//Propiedades
CustomListFragment customListFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list_view);


    //Init fragment
    customListFragment = (CustomListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_customlistview);


}
```

}

Por ultimo, tu layout principal, el fragment, y el item de tu CustomListView

activity_custom_list_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.grupovolada.voladadev.StackOverFlow.CustomListView"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_customlistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"     class="com.grupovolada.voladadev.StackOverFlow.Fragments.CustomListFragment"></fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_customlistview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvCustom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

item_customlistview.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Espero esto solucione tu duda, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

aprovecho este hilo ya que estoy haciendo algo muy parecido, también me está dando problemas y necesito ayuda. En mi caso, el código es el siguiente:

**-fragment_mi_estanteria.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MiEstanteria">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**-fila_lista_miestanteria.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/book_cover_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/book_title_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**-BookItem.java**

```
package com.example.app_tfg;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class BookItem {
static String title_item;
static Drawable cover_item;

public BookItem(){
    super();
}

public BookItem(String title, Drawable cover){
    super();
    this.title_item = title;
    this.cover_item = cover;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title_item;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title_item = title;
}

public static Drawable getCover() {
    return cover_item;
}

public void setCover(Drawable cover) {
    this.cover_item = cover;
}
}
```

**-BookAdapter.java**

```
public class BookAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<BookItem> bookList;
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public BookAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BookItem> bookList) {
    this.bookList = bookList;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return bookList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

static class BookHolder {
    ImageView cover_item;
    TextView title_item;
}

    @Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fila_lista_miestanteria, null);
    BookHolder bookHolder = new BookHolder();
    bookHolder.cover_item = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.book_cover_item);
    bookHolder.title_item = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.book_title_item);

    bookHolder.title_item.setText(bookList.get(i).getTitle());
    return v;
}
}
```

Ahora, mi problema viene cuando quiero juntarlo todo en el Fragment "MiEstanteria". El principal problema que tengo, es que yo quiero rellenar el Listview con datos procedentes de una hoja de cálculo Google Spreadsheets, y no se bien donde hacer esta llamada.

**-MiEstanteria.java**

```
public class MiEstanteria extends ListFragment {
static String read = "si";
ListView bookList;

public MiEstanteria() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

//Se crea el Fragment
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

//Carga layout fragment
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mi_estanteria,container, false);
    bookList = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return view;
}

private void rellenar() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Spreadsheets.class);
    intent.putExtra(read_only,read);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {

    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), GetBookInfo.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.settings:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getActivity(), Ajustes.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            return true;
        case R.id.about:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getActivity(), About.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            return true;
        case R.id.exit:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Salir")
                    .setMessage("¿Estás seguro?").setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //finish();
                }
            }).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

¿Me podríais ayudar? Muchisimas gracias por adelantado!